# Smarty: If Spaces at the Beginning/End of a {Multi Word String}, Trim it/them

Tags: php, smarty, trim

I am trying to figure out how to trim spaces at the beginning/end of a {Multi Word String} in Smarty.

Example:

```
{ tag number one}
{tag number two }
{ tag number two }
```

I need this:

```
{tag number two}
```

Sometime it doesn't even need to be trimmed so it's very random.

I've tried a few solution like {$var|trim} already but I always end up with that:

```
{tagnumberone}
```

Also, {$var|substr:0:-1} or {$var|substr:-1:0} but it's not variable.

Any other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can register pre_filter in smarty to change your template before Smarty parsing

```
// use this function anywhere in code 
function tagFilter($output)
{
   $ret = str_replace('{ ', '{', $output);
   $ret = str_replace(' }', '', $output);

   // or better to use preg:
   //return preg_replace('//valid formula;)//', '', $output);
   
   return $ret;
}

// register filter
$smarty->registerFilter('pre', 'tagFilter');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a try with your smarty but it's not working. That's my fault because I don't really know how to use Smarty. Here the code line in my template without your smarty: <a class="mtags" href="/tags/{$keywords[i]|lower|replace:' ':'+'}"> Should I just pass $keyword in the smarty function in $output and then switch it to $tagFilter in the template?

Comment: No, use this code in php file (where you initiate Smarty example in index.php)